# is it a correct behavior of UriBuilder in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

First example:

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost")
  .queryParam("foo", "test")
  .clone()
  .build()
// equals to: "http://localhost/?foo=test"
```

Second example:

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost")
  .replaceQueryParam("foo", "test")
  .clone()
  .build()
// equals to: "http://localhost/"
```

It should be like this or it's a defect (in Jersey 1.11)?

Comment: Reported to Jersey team: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1081

Comment: Thanks for filing this. It is now fixed in Jersey trunk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a defect in Jersey, and it's already fixed: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1081

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't say why this is happening, but the `clone` method is totally useless here:

```
URI uri1 = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost")
.queryParam("foo", "test")
.build();
//prints http://localhost?foo=test

URI uri2 = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost")
.replaceQueryParam("foo", "2")
.build();
//prints http://localhost?foo=2
```

and even

```
URI uri2 = UriBuilder.fromUri(uri1)
.replaceQueryParam("foo", "2")
.build();
//prints http://localhost?foo=2
```

UPD. about `clone()` method :

> Create a copy of the UriBuilder preserving its state

So it should be used on existing uri to create a new instance of it more efficiently, then building a new one. So I think it is unnecessary here.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the meaning of `clone()` method :) I know what is it for, the code above is just an example. In a real project the scenario is much more complex and `clone()` method is used on purpose

Comment: so maybe you should use it after building a valuable object? Not before the `build()` method?

Comment: You try to clone it while it is not yet builded.

Comment: Yes, and `queryParam()` works just fine. Why `replaceQueryParam()` doesn't?

Comment: as you can see above it was a bug in Jersey and it's already fixed.